# How can I get my token_id ( Auth0 ) from my web app in my TWA?

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, auth0, twa

I am using Auth0 as a provider for authentication, how can I get access to my web app token_id from the TWA ? Or is there a better way to go about it, I need this to set an external_user_id for my onesignal notification push..